# Как анимировать пути в svg с помощью jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, анимация

Проблема с анимацией `svg`. Весь элемент:

```
<path
    inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
    d="m 283.8484,42.9297 -13.6551,0 0,-43.3318 13.6551,0 0,43.3318 z"
    style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
    id="path3013" />
```

Допустим, в этом `svg` элементе нужно с помощью jQuery анимировать строчку

```
d="m 283.8484,42.9297 -13.6551,0 0,-43.3318 13.6551,0 0,43.3318 z"
```

в

```
d="m 283.8484,76.9297 -13.6551,0 0,-43.3318 13.6551,0 0,43.3318 z"
```

Как это реализовать, как подцепиться к атрибуту `d` через jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Значение атрибута `d` можно читать и устанавливать методом jQuery [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Это позволяет получить и менять ту длинную строку.

Предлагаю решение для конкрентного случая, не рассматривая более сложные [пути в SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

Строка начинается с оператора `m` и заканчивается `z`. Их отбросим. Остальное - числа, которые будем плавно менять. Строку без `m` и `z` разбить в массив чисел по пробелам или запятым: `s.split(/[\s\,]/).map(parseFloat)`

Есть два массива чисел. Нужно плавно переехать от значений в одном - к значениями в другом. Значения в одинаковом порядке. Пусть текущее положение в этом переезде меняется переменной `i` от 0 до 100. Тогда текущее значение очередного параметра `from + (to - from) * (i/100)`

Для анимации в jQuery есть метод [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Им можно анимировать не только CSS свойства, но и [абстрактные значения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16857838/556876):

```
$({foo:0}).animate({foo:100}, {
    step: function(val) {
        // переменная val тут пример значения от 0 до 100
    }
})
```

В этой ф-ии будем собирать строку текущих значений, собирая полученные промежуточные значения по очереди через запятую или пробел. И допишем "m " и " z" по краям.

---

**Собираем всё вместе [[фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/u6ogoa8c/)]:**

```
function toArray(s) {
    return s.replace(/^m /,'').replace(/ z$/,'')
    .split(/[\s\,]/).map(parseFloat);
}

function morph(v) { // v = 0 .. 100
    var i, result="";
    for(i=0; i<from.length; i++) {
        result += (from[i] + (to[i] - from[i]) * (v/100));
        result += i%2 ? ' ' : ',';
    }
    result = 'm ' + result + ' z';
    $el.attr('d',result);
}

var $el = $('#path3013')
    ,from = toArray( $el.attr('d'))
    ,to = toArray( 
    "m 283.8484,76.9297 -13.6551,0 0,-43.3318 13.6551,0 0,43.3318 z"
)
;

$({i:0}).animate({i:100}, {step: morph});
```

Спасибо за вопрос! Натолкнул на идеи для реализации морфинга SVG форм. Можно же более сложные формы так же плавно менять одну в другую.

**Upd.** Ещё [способ анимации](https://css-tricks.com/svg-shape-morphing-works/) – через `<animate>`.

Comment: еще вопрос, а если элементов несколько, и все двигаются, по разным путям, то есть элемент, фром и ту разные у всех, можно как то для каждого отдельно не выписывать?